# Is this a bug in GNU Bash?

Tags: bash, command-line

I found this out while attempting to shore up my scripts for string security:

```
$ echo '!!'
!!
$ echo "$(echo '!!')"
echo "$(echo 'echo '!!'')"        #<~ the console echoes the line with expanded history here
echo !!                           #<~ the result
```

It seems to me that the innermost quoting, which is single-quoted, should *not* expand *anything*, variable, subshell, or otherwise, but in this case it expands the `!!` to the last line typed. Seems like it shouldn't do that.

I ask you: is this a bug in Bash, and if it is possible to use a quoted subshell expansion that outputs an exclamation mark?

(Using Bash 4.1.007 in Linux)

**Edit:**

If the above isn't a bug, why, then, does this behave as expected?

```
$ foo='some value'
$ echo "$(echo 'neither $foo nor `this subshell` should expand here')"
neither $foo nor `this subshell` should expand here
```

Comment: Not a bug. It is how bash does argument expansion. Someone will answer with a reference to the relevant part of the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree.

```
$ echo "$(echo '!!')"
echo "$(echo 'echo $(echo '!!')')"
echo $(echo !!)
```

should do the same as

```
$ echo $(echo '!!')
!!
```

I can't see how to explain the difference based on the [history expansion documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction).

It's also odd how the history expansion docs are completely separate from the rest of the [shell expansions documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions).

zsh echoes `!!` for both, at least with my setup.

Comment: Looks like it's a bug.  It's trying to handle the `echo "'!'"` case, and catching `echo "$(echo '!!')"` too.

Comment: The bug was introduced in bash-3.0.  bash-2.05b works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a bug, but `set +H` will disable that (it's off by default in scripts anyway).

Here are the relevant sections from the man page:

> Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the  literal  value  of
>          all  characters  within the quotes, with the exception of $, `, \, and,
>          when history expansion is enabled, !.  The characters $  and  `  retain
>          their  special meaning within double quotes.  The backslash retains its
>          special meaning only when followed by one of the following  characters:
>          $,  `,  ", \, or <newline>.  A double quote may be quoted within double
>          quotes by preceding it with a backslash.  If enabled, history expansion
>          will  be  performed  unless an !  appearing in double quotes is escaped
>          using a backslash.  The backslash preceding the !  is not removed.

and

> History expansion is performed immediately after  a  complete  line  is
>          read,  before  the  shell  breaks it into words. ... History expansions are introduced by
>          the appearance of the  history  expansion  character,  which  is  !  by
>          default.   Only  backslash  (\) and single quotes can quote the history
>          expansion character.

Comment: "Enclosing characters in double quotes..." -- That's just it. The bangs are in single quotes. If it were a variable in there, it *wouldn't* expand.

Comment: @amphetamachine except that single quotes (normally) lose their special meaning when they occur between double-quotes (as they do in this case).  The `$()` does give special meaning back to the single quotes, but apparently bash doesn't parse it in that much detail until after history expansion.  In a sense it *shouldn't* parse it yet, because a history substitution might contain things like `$(` and `'` that might change the quoting status of things around it...

Comment: @amphetamachine: variable substitution (as in your edit) happens in a much later phase of command parsing than history substitution, and follows very different rules.  For instance, if there are quotes in the replacement string for a history substitution, they'll be parsed as though they were typed on the command line; in a history substitution, quotes will have no special meaning.  This is because quote parsing happens after history substitution, but before variable substitution.

Answer (score 1):

If you put your two bangs into a variable, you will get the results you expect (and more string security as well).

```
(
#set -xv
twobangs='!!'
echo "${twobangs}"
echo "$(echo "${twobangs}")"
echo "$(echo 'echo "${twobangs}"')"
echo "$(echo "echo "${twobangs}"")"
echo "$(echo "echo ""${twobangs}")"
#set -xv
)
```

On a similar note, you sometimes can use the shell's builtin string concatenation and just put a character such as '!' into single quotes to prevent interpretation by the shell.

```
(
set -H
echo "Hello, world"'!'
(sleep 10) & 
#trap "echo exit; kill -TERM $!" EXIT HUP INT QUIT TERM  # troublemaker
#trap "echo exit; kill -TERM $"'!' EXIT HUP INT QUIT TERM
trap "echo exit; kill -TERM $"'!'"; echo killed" EXIT HUP INT QUIT TERM
sleep 5
)
```